# How to rename photo filename to include the date?

Tags: command-line, rename, date, filename

I have a group of photo files that are named with only a sequence number like: `Imagexxxx.jpg` (`xxxx` is just a sequence number) what I am trying to search but sadly no results, is to add the date of the file to the filename as the following `yyyy-mm-dd-Imagexxxx.jpg`.

All what I can find on the net is either replacing certain character or changing the letters case.

Comment: I have not used them, and can only suggest looking at the various exif tools. That extracts the internal meta-data and then you can use that to format a name for your file, change timestamps or do other edits. In Synaptic you get a variety of exif tools listed. `sudo apt-get install synaptic`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Krename is one possible tool for what you are trying to accomplish.

Install with:

```
sudo apt-get install krename
```

Then:

1. Select the files you want to rename
2. Choose rename input files in the destination path
3. Enter [creationdate;yyyy-MM-dd]$ in the advanced Filename template.

If creation date (of the file) is not what you want, krename can also use exif data.

Answer (score 0):

I use 'pyRenamer' to rename my photo files.  A very friendly GUI software that can abstract EXIF meta-data from image file.

Answer (score -1):

A slight modification of [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592342/bash-add-suffix-to-all-files-in-the-directory-with-an-extension) will do it.
Run this in a terminal in the directory your photos are in, changing [date] as appropriate (no brackets are needed):

```
for file in *; do mv "$file" "[date]$file"; done
```

Note that this will prepend whatever you choose for [date] to all files in that directory.